# Store multiple inputs in JSON key as part of array

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, arrays, json

Good evening,

I am trying to make a form that is dynamic, meaning that some `<input>` tags can be added by the user with the click of a button. Such behaviour is easely done with javascript, adding an element whenever the user feels like it, appending it to the parent element, in this case a form.

The dynamic nature of the `input` tags comes from the need to store a bunch of values inside an array that must be later pushed inside a mongodb document and the number of elements is not set, hence the dynamic nature. An example, to show what I mean:

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Username and ID</legend>
        <input type="text" name="username" />
        <input type="text" name="uniqueId" />
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Places the user can go to</legend>
        <input type="text" /> <!-- user input would be "pub" -->
        <input type="text" /> <!-- user input would be "market" -->
        <input type="text" /> <!-- user input would be "cinema" -->
        <input type="text" /> <!-- user input would be "computer store" -->

        <!-- other elements, added dynamically -->
        <!-- the user might be able to go also to the gym, or the park,
             he is the one that decides the number of places to add to the
             input -->
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

The thing I would like is for this input values to be stored all together inside an array which is already part of an object, like so:

```
myObject = {
    username: "Ryan",
    uniqueId: "A001",
    canGoTo : [
        "pub", 
        "market",
        "cinema",
        "computer store",
        ...other inputs that the user might have added and wrote]
}
```

The `canGoTo` key would be filled with the values inserted by the user inside the various inputs of that form. How would I go about storing them inside the array `canGoTo`?

EDIT: I am using AngularJS with ng-submit

Comment: are you using jquery?
how will these inputs be added/changed? will they have the ability to change/add/remove at any time?

Comment: If user changes an input value should previous values in array be overwritten?

Comment: I am using angularjs and the input value should not be overwritten if the "form" has been sent to the backend already

Comment: you should add angular as a tag.. this will change the way you approach this.
also mention in the description that you are using angular

Comment: _"I am using angularjs and the input value should not be overwritten if the "form" has been sent to the backend already"_ Not sure gather requirement correctly. If user inputs "a", then changes input to "b" should array element be "a" or "b", or both "a" and "b"?

Comment: if the user submitted the form the value in the array remains "a", per your example. This form creates a user, it doesn't update an existing one.

Comment: @mnemosdev Yes, if user has not submitted form, and changes "a" to "b" at an input field, should array element be "a" or "b"?

Comment: if form is not submitted the value should be "b", per the two-way-binding of angularjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ng-model to target specific indices of an array. Something like:

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Username and ID</legend>
        <input type="text" name="username" />
        <input type="text" name="uniqueId" />
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Places the user can go to</legend>

        <input type="text" ng-repeat="input in myObject.canGoTo"
               ng-model="myObject.canGoTo[$index]" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

To add a new input:

```
$scope.myObject.canGoTo.push ('');
```

You'll need to run some testing on the various functions you offer in terms of manipulating the actual form, but this should be a good launching point.

Answer (score 1):

If you give all the relevant inputs the same class, you can use getElementsByClassName(), and then cycle through the returned array, and do something along the lines of  canGoTo.push(elementArray[i].value) after creating an empty canGoTo array.

If you want to add one at a time, all you need to add is a variable keeping track of the current inputs index number.